# How to identify callback from Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Having an issue with the Facebook PHP API/SDK, let me begin by describing:
I made a website where you can enter 'quotes' (short messages) and then after saving the quote in the website (read; too a mysql db behind it) you can decide to share the quote with Facebook to be able to win stuff.

The flow (how it should work) is this:

1. User opens my site, PHP gets a login url from the Facebook PHP API/SDK
2. PHP reads & memorizes the 'state' url variable from the login url from the above step (which several sites mention would be a valid way to identify users)
3. A user saves a quote, I store the state variable from above in the db record of that quote so I can use it again later to match returning users with saved quotes.
4. The user decides to want to win, so he/she clicks the Facebook share button, which points their browser too the Facebook login url from step 1
5. The user's browser is now looking at some Facebook pages where they have to allow access for the app and allow that it can post to their wall
6. Once the user has given said access, they return to the callback url of my site (which happens to be the same as the 'origin url' from step 4)
7. PHP on my site finds the state variable in the returned url variables(?), goes trough the database to find a matching quote record, and if found, it stores some Facebook user data (userid and path to avatar) in the related db record.
8. PHP continues to post their earlier saved quote to the user's Facebook wall.

In essence, things work, but the most important bit, step 7, identifying who comes back via the state variable, does not. The problem is that I just get some lengthy 'code' GET variable back, and not the 'state' GET variable, and nowhere in the API docs or on StackOverflow or via Google do I find how to change it so I do get the 'state' GET variable returned again...?

So to recap, basically what I'm looking for is an ability to send some sort of identifier to Facebook that then gets included in the callback-url, and to my knowledge, that's what the 'state' variable seems best for, if it would work that is.

I'm using the currently latest API (facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0.zip from this morning) Below I've shared all relevant code I use to interface with the Facebook PHP API/SDK, all this code resides in the index.php in public_html dir of my site, the callback url of my app is this same index.php
This code is pieced together from several examples, and essentially works, I just don't get the needed state variable back.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '<PATH-TOO-FB-API>/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
session_start();

$fbStateCode = ""; // used to memorize state code
$fbLoginUrl = ""; // user to memorize login url

// Init the API
// If you go end up testing this, dont forget too change <APP-ID> & <APP-SECRET>
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '<APP-ID>',
    'app_secret' => '<APP-SECRET>',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
    'default_access_token' => isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']) ? $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] : '<APP-ID>|<APP-SECRET>'
]);

// login helper
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

// try get an accesstoken (wich we only have if user returned from facebook after logging in)
try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    //echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage(); // When Graph returns an error
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    //echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage(); // When validation fails or other local issues
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
    // User is logged in!
    try {
        // Now we look up some details about the user
        $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name');
        $facebook_user = $response->getGraphUser();
        exit; //redirect, or do whatever you want
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        //echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        //echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    // if facebook_user has an id, we assume its a user and continue
    if(isset($facebook_user['id'])) {
        $avatarUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/".$facebook_user['id']."/picture";
        // THE BELOW 8 LINES HANDLE LOADING A QUOTE FROM DB WITH MATCHING STATE AND SAVING
        // ADDITIONAL DATA TOO IT, THE ONLY ISSUE HERE IS THAT $_GET['state'] DOESNT EXIST
        // THE REST OF THIS PROCESS HAS ALREADY BEEN TESTED AND PROOFED TO BE WORKING
        $curr_quote = Quotes::getQuoteByFbStateCode($_GET['state']);
        $curr_quote_data = $curr_quote->getData();
        $curr_quote->updateData(array(
            "fb_access_token" => $accessToken,
            "fb_uid" => $facebook_user['id'],
            "fb_avatar_path" => $avatarUrl
        ));
        // Save it
        if($curr_quote->save()) { // Success! quote in db was updated
            // Now that we are logged in and have matched the returned user with a saved quote, we can post that quote too facebook
            $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken; // storing the access token for possible use in the FB API init
            // This is the data we post too facebook
            $msg_data = array (
                'message' => $curr_quote_data['quote']
            );
            $response = $fb->post('/me/feed',$msg_data,$accessToken); // do the actual post (this, like everything else besides state variable, works)
        } else { // Fail! quote in db was NOT updated?!
            // handle errors
        }
    }
} else {
    // User is NOT logged in
    // So lets build up a login url
    $permissions = ['public_profile','publish_actions']; // we want these permissions (note, atm im the only tester, so while the app still needs to be reviewed for the 'publish_actions' permission, it works cuz i own the app and test with same fb account)
    $fbLoginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://<WEBSITE-URL>/index.php', $permissions); // get the login url from the api providing callback url and permissions array
    $fbLoginUrlParams = array();
    parse_str($fbLoginUrl, $fbLoginUrlParams); // store the url params in a new array so that we can (read next comment below)
    $fbStateCode = $fbLoginUrlParams['state']; // read out and store the state url variable
}
```

Below here is logic for saving a new quote to database based on user interaction, and making use of `$fbStateCode`, this part of the process functions fine as well, quotes get saved with their own unique state values like they should.

So that's the story, I'm trying to do something which I'm pretty sure isn't anything special, it's just poorly documented or something?

Comment: _“you can decide to share the quote with Facebook to be able to win stuff”_ – that is __not allowed__. You should go read [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#properuse), specifically in this instance 4.5: _“Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions.”_ You are not allowed to make users create posts on their own timelines to enter a competition.

Comment: And neither are you allowed to fill the message part of the post for them – the message has to be a 100% user generated, i.e. typed in by the user. So in this form, you will never get your app approved by Facebook in permission review.

Comment: @Cbroe Interesting, thanks for the headsup, will communicate this too the person that asked me to make said site/process.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up rewriting the lot, now it works fine, not sure whats different now vs what i had, so cant really provide an awnser for others running into similair issues, sorry bout that.

@Cbroe; forwarded the headsup you gave me too the customer, got literally told 'not our problem, but the problem of the company that made the concept', so time will tell if this ever even goes online lol, still, thanks for the headsup :P

Answer (score -1):

Read the docs about the `state` variable [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1):

The `state` parameter is a value which is provided by the client prior to the login wen redirecting to the login url. If it's available then, it get's send back in the callback url.

So, unless you provide any state variable in your step1, you won't get any from FB (and any other oAuth2 implementing API). There will not be any "magic" making that appear other than providing it with a feasable state of your PHP app in step 1.

Actually, the state parameter is to give any client the ability to restore a context, whenever the callback "happens". So the content of the state variable may be a session id, a user id or any other value which helps restoring the (php)apps context again after receiving a callback

**EDIT**

I assume, that the state variable needs to be added somewhere in this function here:

```
 $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
```

Comment: Heya's, first off, thanks for your reply, much appreciated. However, i use the native (as in native too the fb sdk) function
`$helper->getLoginUrl('http://<WEBSITE-URL>/index.php', $permissions);`
wich actually builds up a url string that contains state, and i use that url string to start the facebook process (ie; point the user's browser too it) meaning the state actually gets sent too FB, however the callback url gets called with only a 'code' GET variable, but no 'state' GET variable

Comment: @suicidal.banana I think you should read @axel-amthor answer again. "_The `state` parameter is a value which is **provided by the client** prior to the login ..._". If you check the native's source code, `getLoginUrl` method are using `pseudoRandomStringGenerator` class, which mean they are generated from the client side (your app) and obviously will return **random** 'state'. So you will have to create another method to get that already saved **random state** into the `getRedirectLoginHelper' method.

Comment: From the [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#logindialog) : "_`state`. An arbitrary unique string created by your app to guard against Cross-site Request Forgery._"

Comment: @cwps Thanks for the replies, the random state argument is infact generated on my side by `getLoginUrl` like you say, and i do have a method to get that random state argument from the login url (see bottom few lines of snippet) wich i then store for later use (not shown, but described at end of snippet) the problem is that the callback goes to a url like `http://<WEBSITE-URL>/index.php?code=78s6ad8sa6f78d6df87sa6d87sa` with a very long code, and nothing else, the state variable isnt actually returned too the callback url, wich is the problem im trying to overcome.

Comment: @suicidal.banana I was just restating Alex answer. The 'state' is an optional argument that created by your app as an identifier for your API call. **In simple**: "_Hey facebook, when i get my API response, please return the response with this number I just generated, so I know it's from you, not from some other person whos trying to be you_." This conversation happened when you use whatever function in step 1, but **not** in whatever function you use in the step 4. If you use the exact same function, then probably a bug?